# Unable to send Response to Browser containing cookie name when code opens new window using javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets, cookies

I am facing an Issue wherein if I am passing cookie information using httpservlet Response object,cookie is not created in the browser.While debugging i found that,there is javascript code which opens a new window under certain condition and thats when cookie is not created.Can someone help me with that,as I need to create cookie as well which contains information needed to go to my other page.

Comment: Java and Javascript are two very different things.

Comment: How does this relate to java programming?

Comment: This is related to java,as I am trying to create  cookie using Java Httpservlet response object